# How can I wait for observables to complete which aren't guaranteed to emit in the first place?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am trying to figure out how to wait for an observable to be done in order to let another one emit a value.
Basically, backend sends me a series of actions I have to perform as a response to a GET API call.
Let's say the actions are:

- Action 1
- Action 2
- Action 3

Currently, what I am doing is the following for every single action possible:

```
    APIResponse
        .filter{$0.0}
        .subscribe(onNext: { flag in 
             //handle code here
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

So I have three different blocks that look like the one above in my code, one for Action 1, another for Action 2 and another for Action 3.

Today, I did a test and enabled all of my actions at once. I got 2 alerts/view controllers showing on top of each other since all of my observables are emitting at the same time. And I got a warning for the third action which said that the VC was already presenting the alert and it couldn't present the third one (normally so).

I'd like to handle each action on its own no matter what the backend sends me so I could receive one action or 3 at once.
So what I want is to have the VC/alert disappear and completely be done with the handling of an action for another's to start.

If all actions came back empty, I expect the UI to do nothing and keep showing the homescreen.

Can anyone suggest anything useful?

Comment: You should describe what kind of UX you eventually expect when all 3 actions would fail.

Comment: That's why I filter. If it came back empty, I do nothing. The home screen stays as it is. I updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: There's a big difference between an empty response and a server response fail. Please clarify this part what do you exactly mean by an empty action coming back.

Comment: Are all three actions the presentation of an alert?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, this should work:

```
let sharedResponse = apiResponse

let result1 = sharedResponse
    .filter { $0.shouldDoAction1 }
    .flatMap { _ in action1() }

let result2 = sharedResponse
    .filter { $0.shouldDoAction2 }
    .flatMap { _ in action2() }

Observable.concat(result1, result2)
    .withLatestFrom(sharedResponse)
    .filter { $0.shouldDoAction3 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        action3()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The above assumes that `action1()` and `action2()` are of type `() -> Observable<Void>` and that they emit a completed event when they are done performing their action. They will also complete when the response emits a completion event, even if they didn't emit any next events.

My [CLE library](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools) provides wrappers that will turn view controller presentation into an action. For example:

```
let result1 = sharedResponse
    .filter { $0.shouldDoAction1 }
    .flatMap(presentScene(animated: true) { _ in
        UIAlertController(title: "Action1", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            .scene { $0.connectOK() }
    })
```